# Unique id Key from a select top 1 statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

With own id scheme as follow

```
select TOP 1 @docID=id+1 FROM dbo.user_documents WITH (NOLOCK)
ORDER BY ID DESC
...

INSERT INTO dbo.user_Documents ([id],...) Values(@docID,...)
```

as @Erland Sommarskog referes

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3eb9dba6-2f8d-4c48-9aa1-c56f31527690/rowlock-and-updlock-difference?forum=transactsql

two users may get the same id, and says to use UPDLOCK hint prevent that, where

> the process that comes as #2, will be blocked on the SELECT
>   statement

My question is ok makes sense, but after the process #1 passes the select and gets the id and lets the #2 process get also its own id how does it guarantee that #1 process as already inserted its id making the #2 process id different?

Also alternatives would be for this id to be auto-increment (but in this case is not possible) another would be to use NEWID()/GUID that would prevent this problem since it would all's be unique key but changing the primary key of type int to guid type would bring performance issues from some search, is that true? or would possibilite to take in consideration?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all. What are you trying to do? You talk about UPDLOCK but your query has NOLOCK. Then you just kind of ramble on in circles.

Comment: You should consider creating a SEQUENCE in your DB and use this for your IDs. The next val call of the sequence will increase the ID for ALL users. Another idea would be to change the column to an identity column - should work for ALL users as well.

Comment: query that I am using haves NOLOCK, but as refered in the post to use the UPDLOCK, my question is if with that realie prevents from multiple user getting the same id....

Comment: You are asking if NOLOCK and UPDLOCK do the same thing? Not even close. If you found an example using one lock type why would you think you can just randomly pick some other lock type and it will behave the same?

Comment: forget the nolock my question if with the UPDLOCK will prevent the get same id for different users.

Comment: This is a classic XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/ If we understood what you are really trying to do we can offer some actual help. Once you have to resort to query hints you need to step back and ask yourself if what you are doing is the right approach. There are times that yes it is, but you really need to fully understand the hints you are using. Most of the time there is a better way to solve the issue.

Comment: @Tyron78 solution using SEQUENCE works well gonna go with that.